# Delete Parse Table Row based on Username

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

Based on the parse [AnyWall demo for android](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android), and app that shows messages at certain locations, I made a similar app for food, essentially showing what the user is eating. I can successfully post to the Parse table and show the location of the user and what they are eating on a map. However, what I would like to do is when the user creates a new post, their old post gets deleted and their new post is added to the table. Essentially, any given user can only have 1 post on a map at a time. I have seen the `deleteInBackground` method, but cannot seem to find the table to specify and a specific username to specify. How would I go about doing this on Android? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use username as column and you can write before save method on Parse cloud for your table. So when you want add a new record your before save method can detect the duplicate entry on your table and delete it. I hope I understand your question.

Regards.